# Faster to add all items to an array then write the array to file, or faster to write the item to a file and then add to array one at a time?

Tags: python, arrays, file

So right now I have this (in Python 2.7):

```
if y == ports[0]:
   Array1.append(x)
 elif y == ports[1]:
   Array2.append(x)
 elif y == ports[2]:
   Array3.append(x)
 elif y == ports[3]:
   Array4.append(x)
 else:
   Array5.append(x)

for x in Array1:
    target=open('Array1.csv', 'a')
    target.write(x + ",\n")
    target.close()
    print "Added IP address " + x + " to Array1.csv\n"

for x in Array2:
 target=open('Array2.csv', 'a')
 target.write(x + ",\n")
 target.close()
 print "Added IP address " + x + " to Array2.csv\n"

for x in Array3:
 target=open('Array3.csv', 'a')
 target.write(x + ",\n")
 target.close()
 print "Added IP address " + x + " to Array3.csv\n"

for x in Array4:
  target=open('Array4.csv', 'a')
  target.write(x + ",\n")
  target.close()
  print "Added IP address " + x + " to Array4.csv\n"

for x in Array5:
  target=open('Array5.csv', 'a')
  target.write(x + ",\n")
  target.close()
  print "Added IP address " + x + " to Array5.csv\n"
```

Would the program finish quicker if I did:

```
if y == ports[0]:
    Array1.append(x)
    target=open('Array1.csv', 'a')
    target.write(x + ",\n")
    target.close()
    print "Added IP address " + x + " to Array1.csv\n"
elif y == ports[1]:
    Array2.append(x)
    target=open('Array2.csv', 'a')
    target.write(x + ",\n")
    target.close()
    print "Added IP address " + x + " to Array2.csv\n"
elif y == ports[2]:
    Array3.append(x)
    target=open('Array3.csv', 'a')
    target.write(x + ",\n")
    target.close()
    print "Added IP address " + x + " to Array3.csv\n"
elif y == ports[3]:
    Array4.append(x)
    target=open('Array4.csv', 'a')
    target.write(x + ",\n")
    target.close()
    print "Added IP address " + x + " to Array4.csv\n"
else:
    Array5.append(x)
    target=open('Array5.csv', 'a')
    target.write(x + ",\n")
    target.close()
    print "Added IP address " + x + " to Array5.csv\n"
```

Or would I see any difference at all? Or perhaps there is a third way that is quicker? Does it matter when the item is written to the list?

Comment: Why don't you just measure it?

Comment: In either case, I have a suggestion. Instead of having five variables `Array1` through `Array5`, have one list `Arrays`, which contains five arrays. Then your first code could be, `for i in range(5): for x in Array[i]:` instead of five loops in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably barely matters. What’s more important is not constantly reopening the file:

```
with open('Array1.csv', 'a') as target:
    for x in Array1:
        target.write(x + ",\n")
        print "Added IP address " + x + " to Array1.csv\n"
```

Also, I don’t know if it applies here, but [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) *does* exist.